# I cannot open certain apps (Discord, Ubuntu Software Center etc.)

Tags: 20.04, segmentation-fault

I cannot open some certain apps (discord, ubuntu software center etc.) while using Ubuntu 20.04. Terminal said `segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

```
$ discord  
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2NVA.png)

Comment: Ubuntu Software got removed in 20.04, but it can be reinstalled by running `sudo apt install gnome-software`, and it will get renamed from Ubuntu Software to Software. Can you open the newly installed Software app without getting a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` error message?

Comment: thanks for that! i installed it and it worked! but what can i do about discord? @karel

Comment: What are the results of `snap list | grep discord`? A line containing `discord` shows that the discord snap package is installed. If so try `sudo snap refresh discord`. Maybe be able to post this if it works.

Comment: still segmentation error. @karel

Comment: I found these error messages when trying to open discord. `Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"` and `Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"`. This is not just discord, it also effects other snaps, and the bug report was posted yesterday. Do you get this error in the terminal when trying to run `snap run discord`?

Comment: nope, still segmentation error.